# DigitalOcean WordPress Multisite with Multiple droplets and subdomains

Tags: wordpress, digital-ocean, multisite

I'm working on a WordPress project like eBay (WordPress marketplace) and I used the WP multisite to achieve similar results, I'm hosting the project on DigitalOcean, this is my current configuration:

- 1 droplet for the WP multisite app (App server)
- 1 droplet for the WP multisite DB  (Database server)

After sometime the website starts to be very slow and heavy, so I searched for another architecture for this but didn't find much and I need to know if I can run a WordPress Multisite (**mydomain.com on droplet 1**) and install the other subdomains to different/multiple droplets (**subdomain1.mydomain.com on droplet 2**) and (s**ubdomain2.mydomain.com on droplet 3**)... etc. or simply is it possible to use WordPress multisite with multiple different droplets.

[image]

I need to use the previous scenario or any other suggested because I may have many websites under my original WP multisite installed and each one has a huge traffic.